# strange implicit type for eq_refl

Tags: coq

In Coq, propositions are types and proofs are values. For example we may write a simple proof like this, which proves `0=0`.

```
Definition test : (eq 0 0) := eq_refl 0.
```

Interestingly, when checking the type of `eq_refl`, it shows

```
eq_refl
     : ?x = ?x
where
?A : [ |- Type] 
?x : [ |- ?A]
```

That means all the arguments of `eq_refl` are implicit. In Coq, implicit arguments are usually not allowed to determined explicitly, unless using `@`.
To prove `0=0`, we can write explicitly `@eq_refl nat 0` or just `eq_refl` as `nat` and `0` can be deduced. But in the example at beginning, `eq_refl 0` also works. Why?

This thing does not work in general, e.g.

```
Definition foobar {A : Type -> Type} {T : Type} :  list (A T) := [].
Definition test : list (list nat) := foobar.
Fail Definition test' : list (list nat) := foobar nat.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implicit arguments structures of constants may sometimes rely on several
`Arguments` directives, as can be seen in the file `$COQLIB/theories/Init/Logic.v`, lines 309 and 310, reproduced here:

```
Arguments eq {A} x _.
Arguments eq_refl {A x} , [A] x.
```

The use of the `Arguments` command is documented [here](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/gallina-ext.html#hevea_command59), but I did not see it mentioned that several implicit arguments configuration are accepted.

On the other hand, the command `Print Implicit eq_refl.` returns precise information about the fact that two methods of understanding implicit arguments can be used, one when the functions receives 1 argument, and when the function receives 0 arguments.

Comment: The same information about implicit arguments can be obtained with `About eq_refl`.